# std::unordered_map ordering change while traversing during different executions

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unordered-map

Suppose there is `class Heavy` with a bunch of user-defined compound class members. One of that, let's name it `m_hashMap`, has `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::vector<CompoundClass>>` structure. Let we have also `void Heavy::foo() const;` function which is reading all the members of `Heavy` traversing through all container members as well, including `m_hashMap`. The strange behavior that I met during running the code at different times is that `m_hashMap` is being traversed with different ordering in `foo()`, whereas the size and all the elements inside it were the same. No explicit hashing function was provided. What can be the reasons for such behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue: you are saying the `unordered_map` is unordered, and every time you iterate it you are experiencing a different order? Well, that's what the name promises??

Answer (score 0):

Two unordered_map can have different internal bucket layout even with the same set of elements. You can use the `begin`, `end`, `bucket_count`, `bucket_size` and `bucket` methods to monitor or determine whether the internal bucket layout of `m_hashMap` is the same in different execution. For example:

```
template <class T>
void printState(unordered_map<unsigned int, T> &m) {
    int n_buckets = m.bucket_count();
    for(int i = 0; i < n_buckets; i++) {
        cout << "Bucket " << i << ": ";
        for(auto iter = m.begin(i), enditer = m.end(i); iter != enditer; iter++) {
            cout << iter->first << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

printState(m_hashMap);
```

Comment: But you are mutating the container, that's why rehashing happens, whereas in my example `foo()` is `const` function and no state change happens for the `m_hashMap` member

Comment: Hello @Hayk , I think using bucket interfaces provided by unordered_map to inspect the internal structure of ```m_hashMap``` might help you. You can refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#bucket_interface for more detailed usage. If the internal structure of ```m_hashMap``` stay unchanged, the traversal order should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of an `unordered_map` is its own business, and it can rebalance itself (or whatever else it likes to do) when it sees fit, even while appearing `const` to the outside.

As the name says, you cannot rely on the order being stable. The mere ***execution of an iteration*** or a search can trigger a change in the internal representation that results in a different perceived 'order'. This is not related to the hash function, but to the internal representation, which *may* be a red-black tree, or whatever else the developer chose. For example, if the sequence of adding values resulted in an unbalanced tree, the internal code can trigger a balancing when encountering the imbalance during an iteration.

If you are relying on an order, you need to use an ordered map.

Comment: yes, you are right, the order is unknown unless the hash function is unknown as well, but it doesn't matter if I run the same code different times the traversing order should be the same. Suppose this fragment of code
 `unordered_map<int, string> m_hashMap{{1,"first},{2,"second"},{3, "third"},{4,"forth"},{5,"fifth"},{0, "zero"},{7, "seventh"},{6, "sixth"}};

    for(const auto& elem : m_hashMap) {
cout << elem.first <<" "<<elem.second<<'\n';} `

The output is the same regardless of the time this code is executed. I wonder what can be the reason for the different outputs

Comment: The hash function has no relation to the stability of the order. i have added some more explanation.